# TypeError: parser_f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding_errors'

Tags: python

I've tried to upload the following file .csv in mmy notebook of Jupiter, however, when I'm traying to execute the code but I got an exception:
TypeError: parser_f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding_errors'

Code:

df = pd.read_csv('DetalleCliente_20220309_3.csv',sep=';',header=0, decimal=',', encoding_errors='replace')

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
1 # carga del fichero DetalleCliente
2 #, ,sep=';',header=0, decimal=',', encoding_errors='replace'
----> 3 df = pd.read_csv('DetalleCliente_20220309_3.csv',sep=';',header=0, decimal=',', encoding_errors='replace')
4 #df = pd.read_csv('DetalleCliente_20220309_3.csv',sep=';',header=0, decimal=',', encoding='utf8', parse_dates=['ANOMES__C'])

TypeError: parser_f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding_errors'

Thanks

Comment: Error! C:\Users\DetalleCliente_20220309_3.csv is not UTF-8 encoded. Can be this?

Answer (score 1):

Check the version of pandas you're using. encoding_errors was added in version 1.3.0.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html